# std::system_error occurs at Protobuf ParseFromZeroCopyStream()

Tags: c++, ubuntu, protocol-buffers, zlib

I'm testing protobuf with zlib compression.

I wrote some c++ sample code using protobuf 3.8.0, but the following error occurred at calling `ParseFromZeroCopyStream()` at Ubuntu.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1
(core dumped)
```

what can I do?

I tried to replace `ParseFromZeroCopyStream()` with `ParseFromBoundedZeroCopyStream()`.
That results in no core dump, but `ParseFromBoundedZeroCopyStream()` returned false.

**test.proto**

```
syntax = "proto2";

package test;

message Msg
{
    required uint32 data = 1;
}
```

**test.cc**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.h>
#include <google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.h>
#include <google/protobuf/io/gzip_stream.h>
#include "test.pb.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace google::protobuf;
using namespace test;

int main(void)
{
    Msg srcMsg; 
    srcMsg.set_data(1);

    long sSize = srcMsg.ByteSizeLong();
    cout << "SerializedSize = " << sSize << endl;

    char * compressedMsg = new char[sSize];
    io::ArrayOutputStream aos(compressedMsg, sSize); 
    io::GzipOutputStream gos(&aos);

    long cSize;
    if (srcMsg.SerializeToZeroCopyStream(&gos) == true)
    {
        gos.Close();
        cSize = aos.ByteCount();
        cout << "compression success : " << cSize << " bytes" << endl;
    }
    else    
    {
        cout << "compression error" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    Msg targetMsg;

    io::ArrayInputStream ais(compressedMsg, cSize); 
    io::GzipInputStream gis(&ais);

    if (targetMsg.ParseFromZeroCopyStream(&gis) == false)
    {
        cout << "decompression error" << endl;
    }
    else    
    {
        cout << "decompression success : " << targetMsg.ByteSizeLong() << " bytes" << endl;
        cout << "data = " << targetMsg.data() << endl;
    }

    delete[] compressedMsg;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect that decompression succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to learn to use a debugger to investigate further why exactly this "unknown error: -1" is thrown - if possible.

That being said, unknown library errors is ***sometimes*** caused by a failed memory allocation or in rarer cases some other ressource constraint like failing to start a thread/process, etc.